# Calculate Accuracy Between Machine and Human

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, evaluate

I have build my ML model in classification task, then I want to calculate the prediction by machine, compared with prediction by human. How do I get the accuracy of machine's prediction compared with human's prediction? And how many person/s did I must have(minimum) to compare with machine?